# JSON parsing whitespace error React frontend and Laravel backend

Tags: reactjs, json, laravel

I am building a contract system for a client and I have a table with an onClick to open up a modal with the contract details.  Each contract has many services and each service has many fields.  Not all fields are required to be filled in.  I am having an issue with parsing the data and keep getting console errors that shut the page down.  I'm using Vite as my prod builder.  My Contract Wizard is set to combine everything into one information cell for the field, even though a field may have multiple inputs.

Here is the code for the modal:

```
<Modal
  title="Contract Details"
  visible={isDetailsModalVisible}
  onCancel={() => {
    setSelectedContract(null);
    setIsDetailsModalVisible(false);
  }}
  footer={null}
  destroyOnClose
  width="80vw"
  style={{
    minWidth: '80vw',
    maxWidth: '80vw',
    maxHeight: '80vh',
    minHeight: '80vh',
    height: '80vh',
  }}
>
  {selectedContract && (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginBottom: '10px',
        position: 'sticky',
        top: '0',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        zIndex: '1',
        transform: 'scale(0.9)',
      }}
      >
        <div>
          <div style={{ width: '30%' }}>
      <Row>
        <h4>{getStatusText(selectedContract.contract.status)}</h4>
      </Row>
      <Row>
      <QuickActionButtons
          text1={text1}
          text2="Button 2"
          onClick1={onClick1}
          onClick2={() => console.log('Button 2 clicked!')}
          visible={true}
          disabled1={false}
          disabled2={true}
        />
      </Row>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
    <div style={{ width: '58%', marginRight: '2%' }}>
      <h2>Client Info</h2>
      <p>Client Name: {selectedContract.contract.client.clientName || ''}</p>
    </div>
    <div style={{ width: '40%', marginLeft: '2%' }}>
      <h2>People</h2>
      {/* People Data Here */}
    </div>
  </div>
  <Divider />
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
      <div style={{ width: '15%', marginRight: '2%', marginLeft: '2%' }}>
        <p>PO Number: {selectedContract.contract.po_number}</p>
      </div>
      <div style={{ width: '21%', marginRight: '2%', marginLeft: '2%' }}>
        <p>Execution Month: {getMonthName(selectedContract.contract.execution_month)}</p>
      </div>
      <div style={{ width: '29%', marginRight: '2%', marginLeft: '2%' }}>
        <p>Sales Rep: {/* Sales Rep data */}</p>
      </div>
      <div style={{ width: '31%', marginRight: '2%', marginLeft: '2%' }}>
        <p>Production Rep: {/* Production Rep data */}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Divider />
<div ref={containerRef}>
  {selectedContract?.services_with_fields?.map((serviceWithFields, index) => (
    <div key={index} ref={(el) => (headerRef.current[index] = el)} style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
      <Divider>{serviceWithFields?.service?.serviceName}</Divider>
      {serviceWithFields?.fields?.map((field, fieldIndex) => (
        <div key={fieldIndex}>
          <p>
            {field.fieldName}: {field.fieldInput1 !== null ? field.fieldInput1 : 'N/A'}
          </p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
    </div>
  )}
  <DetailsChangeModal 
  selectedContract={selectedContract}
  visible={isDetailChangeModalVisible}
  onCancel={() => setIsDetailChangeModalVisible(false)}
      />
</Modal>
```

Here are the appropriate functions and objects:

```
  const [selectedMenuItem, setSelectedMenuItem] = useState('all');
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [isDetailsModalVisible, setIsDetailsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [contractsData, setContractsData] = useState([]);
  const [renewalsContractsData, setRenewalsContractsData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedContract, setSelectedContract] = useState(null);
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) || {};
  const userType = user.role;
  const [statusValue, setStatusValue] = useState();
  const [isDetailChangeModalVisible, setIsDetailChangeModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const headerRef = useRef([]);

 const fetchContractsData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('api/contracts');
      const contracts = response.data?.contracts?.map((contract) => ({
        client: contract?.contract?.client?.clientName || '', 
        contractType: contract?.contract?.package || '',
        contractData: contract,
        executionMonth: getMonthName(contract?.contract?.execution_month),
        status: getStatusText(contract?.contract?.status),
        changeRequests: 0,
      })) || [];
      setContractsData(contracts);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('An error occurred while fetching contracts data:', error);
    }
  };
```

Here are the actual errors:

```
index-ab24b42d.js:40 SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 4
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at index-ab24b42d.js:494:31825
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at index-ab24b42d.js:494:31610
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at uRe (index-ab24b42d.js:494:31348)
    at kO (index-ab24b42d.js:38:19551)
    at _G (index-ab24b42d.js:40:44101)
    at DG (index-ab24b42d.js:40:39819)
    at wue (index-ab24b42d.js:40:39745)
k$ @ index-ab24b42d.js:40
r.callback @ index-ab24b42d.js:40
dI @ index-ab24b42d.js:38
OI @ index-ab24b42d.js:40
EG @ index-ab24b42d.js:40
yue @ index-ab24b42d.js:40
Sue @ index-ab24b42d.js:40
Xh @ index-ab24b42d.js:40
AG @ index-ab24b42d.js:40
E @ index-ab24b42d.js:25
R @ index-ab24b42d.js:25
index-ab24b42d.js:494 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 4
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at index-ab24b42d.js:494:31825
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at index-ab24b42d.js:494:31610
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at uRe (index-ab24b42d.js:494:31348)
    at kO (index-ab24b42d.js:38:19551)
    at _G (index-ab24b42d.js:40:44101)
    at DG (index-ab24b42d.js:40:39819)
    at wue (index-ab24b42d.js:40:39745)
```

And here is the start of the response, as well as one contract entry.  This will not have open/close brackets as the full response is nearly 5000 lines long:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "contracts": [
        {
            "contract": {
                "id": 227,
                "client_id": 629,
                "package": 12,
                "status": 2,
                "contract_price": 4300,
                "contract_notes": null,
                "execution_month": "8",
                "created_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-08-21T14:24:24.000000Z",
                "po_number": null,
                "client": {
                    "id": 629,
                    "clientName": "Acura of Stockton",
                    "rep_id": 16,
                    "prod_id": null,
                    "type": "2",
                    "status": "1",
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null,
                    "group_id": 4
                }
            },
            "clientName": "Acura of Stockton",
            "services_with_fields": [
                {
                    "service": {
                        "id": 27,
                        "serviceName": "Conquest Email",
                        "active": 1,
                        "updated_at": "2023-08-09T14:44:26.000000Z",
                        "created_at": "2023-08-09T14:44:26.000000Z"
                    },
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "id": 3597,
                            "fieldName": "Add Fill",
                            "yIndex": 34,
                            "fieldType": "Yes/No",
                            "fieldInput1": null,
                            "fieldEdit1": null,
                            "fieldStatus": null,
                            "required": 0,
                            "format_notes": null,
                            "contract_id": 227,
                            "contract_service_id": 592,
                            "created_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "updated_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "field_id": 25
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3598,
                            "fieldName": "Exclusions",
                            "yIndex": 35,
                            "fieldType": "Long Text",
                            "fieldInput1": null,
                            "fieldEdit1": null,
                            "fieldStatus": null,
                            "required": null,
                            "format_notes": null,
                            "contract_id": 227,
                            "contract_service_id": 592,
                            "created_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "updated_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "field_id": 18
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3599,
                            "fieldName": "Specific Zips",
                            "yIndex": 13,
                            "fieldType": "Long Text",
                            "fieldInput1": null,
                            "fieldEdit1": null,
                            "fieldStatus": null,
                            "required": null,
                            "format_notes": "\"Comma Delimited list of zip codes i.e. '42101, 42103, etc'\"",
                            "contract_id": 227,
                            "contract_service_id": 592,
                            "created_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "updated_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "field_id": 29
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3600,
                            "fieldName": "Notes",
                            "yIndex": 36,
                            "fieldType": "Long Text",
                            "fieldInput1": null,
                            "fieldEdit1": null,
                            "fieldStatus": null,
                            "required": null,
                            "format_notes": null,
                            "contract_id": 227,
                            "contract_service_id": 592,
                            "created_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "updated_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "field_id": 19
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3601,
                            "fieldName": "Makes",
                            "yIndex": 15,
                            "fieldType": "Multiselect Dropdown",
                            "fieldInput1": null,
                            "fieldEdit1": null,
                            "fieldStatus": null,
                            "required": null,
                            "format_notes": null,
                            "contract_id": 227,
                            "contract_service_id": 592,
                            "created_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "updated_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "field_id": 17
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3602,
                            "fieldName": "Quantity",
                            "yIndex": 35,
                            "fieldType": "Number",
                            "fieldInput1": null,
                            "fieldEdit1": null,
                            "fieldStatus": null,
                            "required": 1,
                            "format_notes": null,
                            "contract_id": 227,
                            "contract_service_id": 592,
                            "created_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "updated_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "field_id": 34
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "service": {
                        "id": 23,
                        "serviceName": "Digital",
                        "active": 1,
                        "updated_at": "2023-07-19T16:30:38.000000Z",
                        "created_at": "2023-07-19T16:30:38.000000Z"
                    },
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "id": 3603,
                            "fieldName": "Radius",
                            "yIndex": 12,
                            "fieldType": "Number",
                            "fieldInput1": null,
                            "fieldEdit1": null,
                            "fieldStatus": null,
                            "required": 1,
                            "format_notes": "\"Radius always has radio button that can be selected to instead use specific zip codes\"",
                            "contract_id": 227,
                            "contract_service_id": 593,
                            "created_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "updated_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "field_id": 16
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3604,
                            "fieldName": "Social",
                            "yIndex": 23,
                            "fieldType": "Single Select Dropdown",
                            "fieldInput1": null,
                            "fieldEdit1": null,
                            "fieldStatus": null,
                            "required": null,
                            "format_notes": null,
                            "contract_id": 227,
                            "contract_service_id": 593,
                            "created_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "updated_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "field_id": 35
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3605,
                            "fieldName": "Notes",
                            "yIndex": 36,
                            "fieldType": "Long Text",
                            "fieldInput1": null,
                            "fieldEdit1": null,
                            "fieldStatus": null,
                            "required": null,
                            "format_notes": null,
                            "contract_id": 227,
                            "contract_service_id": 593,
                            "created_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "updated_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "field_id": 19
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3606,
                            "fieldName": "Lead Gen Timeframe End",
                            "yIndex": 26,
                            "fieldType": "Date Range",
                            "fieldInput1": null,
                            "fieldEdit1": null,
                            "fieldStatus": null,
                            "required": 0,
                            "format_notes": null,
                            "contract_id": 227,
                            "contract_service_id": 593,
                            "created_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "updated_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "field_id": 7
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3607,
                            "fieldName": "Google Search",
                            "yIndex": 21,
                            "fieldType": "Yes/No",
                            "fieldInput1": null,
                            "fieldEdit1": null,
                            "fieldStatus": null,
                            "required": null,
                            "format_notes": null,
                            "contract_id": 227,
                            "contract_service_id": 593,
                            "created_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "updated_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "field_id": 26
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3608,
                            "fieldName": "Google Display",
                            "yIndex": 22,
                            "fieldType": "Yes/No",
                            "fieldInput1": null,
                            "fieldEdit1": null,
                            "fieldStatus": null,
                            "required": null,
                            "format_notes": null,
                            "contract_id": 227,
                            "contract_service_id": 593,
                            "created_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "updated_at": "2023-08-21T09:58:05.000000Z",
                            "field_id": 27
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
```

I've tried different levels of parsing and error handling.  Here are two things I tried with no success:

```
 function parseFieldInput(input) {
    try {
      const parsed = JSON.parse(input);
      return `${parsed.from} - ${parsed.to}`;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error parsing field input:', input, error);
      return '';
    }
  }
  function formatFieldInput(input) {
    try {

      const parsed = JSON.parse(input);

      if (parsed.from && parsed.to) {
        return `${parsed.from} - ${parsed.to}`;
      }

    } catch (e) {

      const date = new Date(input);
      if (!isNaN(date)) {
        return date.toLocaleDateString();
      }
    }
```